# Double Holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose I have two complex bivariate homolorphic functions $f(z,w)$ and $g(z,w$) such that

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial w} $$
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial w} = - \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} $$

That is, the two functions behave as a "super-holomorphic" function.

Have these functions been studied? do they have interesting integral, analytic or geometric properties and/or interpretations that generalize from the Cauchy-Riemann equations? Can these functions generate four-dimensional conformal mappings? any references?

Comment: Your equation is equivalent to 
$$\left(\partial_z+i\partial_w\right)( f + i g ) = \left(\partial_z -i\partial _w\right)( f - i g ) = 0
\implies
\begin{cases}
f + ig &= A(z+iw)\\
f - ig &= B(z-iw)
\end{cases}
$$
for some holomorphic functions $A,B$.